# Tensorflow memory stack management

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using tensorflow for NIfTI files, a.k.a .nii files. I made a model, opened session, and ran code. My codes are as follows:

```
def memory_usage_psutil():
    # return the memory usage in GB
    import psutil
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem = process.memory_info()[0] / float(2 ** 30)
    return mem


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for epoch in range(50):
for batch in range(len(imgs)//batch_size):

    batch_imgs = [i.get_fdata() for i in imgs[batch*batch_size: (batch+1)*batch_size]]
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        _, loss_val = sess.run([train, loss], feed_dict = {X:batch_imgs, Y:fi_train[batch*batch_size:(batch+1)*batch_size]})

    print(epoch+1, '-th Epoch |', batch+1, '-th batch | Loss : ', loss_val)
    print('Memory usage: %s (kb)'% resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss)
    print("Memory usage: %s(gb)"%memory_usage_psutil())

    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    del _
    del batch_imgs
    del loss_val
```

And its results are as follows:

[image: result capture]

In short, my computer's memory usage continuously increases though I used code

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
del _
del batch_imgs
del loss_val
```

Futhermore, I tried`tf.contrib.keras.backend.clear_session()`, `tf.reset_default_graph()` but they don't work. How can I fix this problem? Anyone knows?

Comment: https://forums.fast.ai/t/tip-clear-tensorflow-gpu-memory/1979
have you tried this ?

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain Yes I have but it doesn't work, too